# Why do eye poses not record in the animation?

Tags: animation

My animation works well except that the eye positions (rotations) do not record. I have rigged the eyes with IK and with Damped Track (separately of course) both methods work to animate beautifully but neither record in the timeline.

I have animated (in pose mode) in the timeline with the auto keyframe (circle icon in the player controls) and I have used the keyboard (I) command. Both seem to work. But when I scrub back to the frame where the pose was set, it has disappeared.

I have also tried setting the poses with all the eye rig bones selected, not just the control bone. Still no joy. I've run out of ideas.

Any helpful suggestions welcome.

Comment: hello, have you checked if the tracks are unlocked in the Dope Sheet? maybe share your file?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your comments. Before posting the question I closed down the file deciding to 'sleep on it'. On opening it up this morning I find that the eye animations had saved and are now working as desired. Unfortunately that means that whatever was happening yesterday has not been identified and will probably return to bite my backside in the near future.
Thanks for help.